# Countdown with sockets would run twice ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sockets

I am trying to set a counter with socket io. Basically the connection is working and the server sends the counter to the client but there is an error. For example I have just opened the server so it start (10, 9, 8, 7) refreshing every second, then I reload the page and I can see this (10, 6, 9, 5, 8, 4) every 0.5 seconds. Here is my code:
server index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require("http");
const { Server } = require('socket.io');
const cors = require("cors")

app.use(cors())

const server = http.createServer(app)

const io = new Server(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: "http://localhost:3000",
        methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    },
});
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    var counter = 10;
    var WinnerCountdown = setInterval(function(){
      io.sockets.emit('counter', counter);
      counter--
      if (counter === 0) {
        io.sockets.emit('counter', "Congratulations You WON!!");
        clearInterval(WinnerCountdown);
      }
    }, 1000);
  });


server.listen(3001, () => {
    console.log("SERVER IS RUNNING");
});
```

client App.js

```
const socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3001");

const App = () => {
      const [counter, setCounter] = useState();
      useEffect(() => {
        socket.on("counter", counter => {
            setCounter(counter);
            console.log("test");
        });
    }, [socket])
    return (
        <h1>{counter}</h1>
                
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's happening because `useEffect` is running twice from version 17 with strict mode.

> StrictMode renders components twice (on dev but not production) in order to detect any problems with your code and warn you about them (which can be quite useful).

If you want to run just once, you can use a `true/false flag`.

```
const socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3001");
let sent = false;

const App = () => {
      const [counter, setCounter] = useState();
      useEffect(() => {
        if (!sent) {
          socket.on("counter", counter => {
            setCounter(counter);
            console.log("test");
          });
          sent = true;
        }
        return () => sent = false;
    }, [socket])
    return (
        <h1>{counter}</h1>
                
    );
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't solve my problem. Also my strict mode is off, so something else must be going on